# Appium fails launching on iPhone Simulator, success on device

Tags: ios, iphone, testing, appium, simulator

- Appium v1.15.1
- Mac 10.14.6
- Xcode 11.2.1
- Python test file.

I'm able to run the test on iPhone Device successfully, but on iPhone Simulator not.

Error:

```
[debug] [WD Proxy] Matched '/status' to command name 'getStatus'
[debug] [WD Proxy] Proxying [GET /status] to [GET http://localhost:8100/status] with no body
[HTTP] --> GET /status
[HTTP] {}
[debug] [HTTP] No route found. Setting content type to 'text/plain'
[HTTP] <-- GET /status 404 1 ms - 49
[HTTP] 
[WD Proxy] Got an unexpected response with status 404: The URL '/status' did not map to a valid resource
```

This is the Appium Server details:

```
Welcome to Appium v1.15.1
[Appium] Non-default server args:
[Appium]   address: 127.0.0.1
[Appium]   port: 8100
[Appium] Appium REST http interface listener started on 127.0.0.1:8100
```

Capabilities (Python):

```
def setUp(self):

        app = ('/Users/...app')
        self.driver = webdriver.Remote(
            command_executor='http://127.0.0.1:8100/wd/hub',
            desired_capabilities={
                'app': app,
                'platformName': 'iOS',
                'platformVersion': '13.1',
                'deviceName': 'iPhone Simulator',
                "automationName": "XCUITest",
                "xcodeOrgId": "XXXXXXXX",
                "xcodeSigningId": "iPhone Developer"
            }
        )
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Did you try with the default port **4723**?

Comment: @SoorajSathianandan With port 4723 and the UDID, its now working!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with the below capabilities:

```
desired_capabilities={
            'app': app,
            'platformName': 'iOS',
            'platformVersion': '13.1',
            'deviceName': 'iPhone Simulator',
            'udid': 'unique id of simulator',
            "automationName": "XCUITest"              
        }
```

udid can be found in **Simulator>Hardware>Device>Manage Device** select the device and then you can see the Identifier.

Port need to be 4723.

Answer (score 0):

"deviceName", "platformVersion" capability should be equal to the device simulator name.

Something like this,

```
capabilities.setCapability("deviceName", "iPhone 8 Plus");
capabilities.setCapability("platformVersion", "12.2");
capabilities.setCapability("automationName": "XCUITest");
```

P.S - iPhone X, XS is not working for me [because of the 'X' I guess!]